# Updating SQL Server 2008 View

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to update an SQL Server 2008 view and when I run the following script I get the following error.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'oas_AppVend')
```

ERROR:

```
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near ')'.
```

If I run the sript like below (no if and no parenthesis), the result shows me the "VIEW'.

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'oas_AppVend'
```

RESULT:

```
TABLE_NAME
oas_AppVend
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the entire SQL script?

Comment: Need more info, like before/after the IF statement...

Answer (score 2):

That error is simply because the script as you've written it isn't enough.  The SQL engine is still needing to know what to do after the if.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS  
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'oas_AppVend') 
BEGIN 
   /* VALID SQL STATEMENT MUST EXIST HERE */
END
```

Note: even the code above will return an error until you put a valid sql statement into the block where I've noted.  If you have desired results for an else it would look like this, again however this isn't a valid statement until you actually finish it out.

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS  
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'oas_AppVend') 
BEGIN 
   /* VALID SQL STATEMENT MUST EXIST HERE */
END
ELSE
BEGIN
   /* DO SOMETHING ELSE */
END
```

Comment: Can I create this as a procedure so a user can run it or would I as the programmer need to go in and run it each time?  Last question, should the View update automatically if records in the base table(s) change?  Thanks again.

Ken

Comment: Yes, the code sample provided above can be used inside a stored procedure.  You can put any other valid SQL statements in the blocks identified and as long as the user running the proc has rights it will work fine.  To your second Q yes, a view is just a stored select statement... so whatever is in the table that the view is based on will be what is reflected in the view anytime it is run.